# Dome rotation on arbitrary axis?

Tags: matlab, 3d, rotation, linear-algebra

Imagine a dome with its centre in the +z direction. What I want to do is to move that dome's centre to a different axis (e.g. 20 degrees x axis, 20 degrees y axis, 20 degrees z axis). How can I do that ? Any hint/tip helps.

Add more info:

I've been dabbling with rotation matrices in wiki for a while. The problem is, it is not a commutative operation. RxRyRz is not same as RzRyRx. So based on the way I multiple it I get a different final results. For example, I want my final projection to have 20 degrees from the original X axis, 20 degrees from original Y axis and 20 degrees from original Z axis. Based on the matrix, giving alpha, beta, gamma values 20 (or its corresponding radian) does NOT result the intended rotation. Am I missing something? Is there a matrix that I can just put the intended angles and get it at the end ?

Comment: What are you using? OpenGL? DirectX? Some sort of 3D software?

Comment: I am using Matlab. So I want to know the theory to implement it

Comment: Not sure if it applies, but have you checked `help rotate`?

Comment: I don't think that "20 degrees from the x/y/z axis" makes sense. How can you be 20 degrees from all of them? Can you explain what you want in a different way?

Comment: Oh I meant like moving a point 20 degrees towards xz plane, 20 degrees towards xy plane and 20 degrees towards yz plane. Other words, rotating the x,y,z axis in an arbitraty angle.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) is an easy way to rotate a collection of (x,y,z) points. You can calculate a rotation matrix for your case using the equations in the [general rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#General_rotations) section. Note that figuring out the angle values to plug into those equations can be tricky. Think of it as rotating about one axis at a time and remember that the order of your rotations (order of multiplications) does matter.

An alternative to the general rotation equations is to [calculate a rotation matrix from axis and angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle). It may be easier for you to define correct parameters with this method.

**Update:** After perusing Wikipedia, I found a simple way to calculate rotation axis and angle between two vectors. Just fill in your starting and ending vectors for `a` and `b` here:

```
a = [0.0 0.0 1.0];
b = [0.5 0.5 0.0];
vectorMag = @(x) sqrt(sum(x.^2));
rotAngle = acos(dot(a,b) / (vectorMag(a) * vectorMag(b)))
rotAxis = cross(a,b)

rotAxis =
    -0.5          0.5            0
rotAngle =
    1.5708
```

Comment: I've been dabbling on these matrices for a while. The problem is, it is not commutative operation. RxRyRz is not same as RzRyRx. So based on the way I multiple it I get a different final results. For example, I want my final projection to have 20 degrees from the original X axis, 20 degrees from original Y axis and 20 degrees from original Z axis. Based on the matrix, giving alpha, beta, gamma values 20 (or its corresponding radian) does NOT result the intended rotation. Am I missing something? 

Is there a matrix that I can just put the intended angles and I get it at the end ?